# Assigning a channel to a category in discord.js

Tags: node.js, promise, discord, discord.js

I have a bot which creates a channel inside of a Discord server. I have been having trouble assigning the channel to a category.

My code:

```
    if (!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR)")) return message.reply("nope");
if (command === "open") {
if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send('Proper usage: *open <name>');
let botmessage = args.join(" ");
message.guild.createChannel('' + botmessage, { type: 'text' })
channel.setParent('[ID of Category here]')
```

The bot successfully creates the channel however it does not assign in to the category. The error I get is:

> 'channel' is not defined.

I am still learning promises and discord.js in general.
How could I get my Discord bot to assign the created channel to a specified category?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `.then()` to get the resolved channel:

```
message.guild.createChannel('' + botmessage, { type: 'text' }).then((channel) => {
    channel.setParent('[ID of Category here]');
});
```

And it will work.
Note that you can also create a channel with a parent option:

```
message.guild.createChannel('' + botmessage, { type: 'text', parent: '[ID of Category here]' });
```

With this way you don't need to use promises and you will have better performances.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I got it working perfectly :)